# Move temporary object outside member function

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, rvalue-reference, rvalue

Here's what I want to create:

```
class Theme
{
    public:
        Theme();

        bool isValid() const;

        QString name() const;

    private:
        QString m_name;
};

class ThemeManager
{
    public:
        ThemeManager();
        ~ThemeManager();

        void setCurrentTheme(const Theme& theme);
        const Theme& currentTheme() const;

        const Theme& theme(const QString& name) const;

    private:
        Theme& m_currentTheme;
        QSet<Theme> m_availableThemes;
};
```

Here comes the tricky part:

```
const Theme& ThemeManager::theme(const QString& name) const
{
    for (const Theme& theme : m_availableThemes)
    {
        if (name == theme.name())
        {
            return theme;
        }
    }

    return Theme();
}
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
ThemeManager m;

const Theme& t = theme("monokai");
if (t.isValid()) {
    // Theme is valid
} else {
    // Theme is not valid
}
```

`ThemeManagers` keeps a list of themes and a reference to the current one. I want to use references instead of pointers. Now if a theme it is asked for is not present in the manager's list of themes, I would like to return a reference to an invalid one which I can test using `Theme::isValid`. I wouldn't like to use a separate member e.g. `Theme m_invalidTheme;` just for this purpose.

My question is: isn't there any way to move a temporary object outside from `ThemeManager::theme` scope? So that `t` from `t.isValid()` is not a dangling reference which breaks the code?

Comment: Have a `const` global `badTheme` you can return. Also eliminates the need for  `isValid`, check the address of the returned theme to see if it matches `badTheme`

Comment: @user4581301 That is for sure a solution. But is it possible to avoid the global `badTheme` variable or a static const `badTheme` member? I would find it more elegant if I could just move the temporary outside and have its lifecycle managed by the ThemeManager's user

Comment: How up to date is your compiler? [Is `std::optional` available?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: @JacobKrieg Why?  I don't see the point.

Comment: Somewhat related - how is `setCurrentThreme` supposed to work? `m_currentTheme` is a reference - these have to be initialized in constructor, and are immutable afterwards.